# Is it possible to do groupingGroupBy without making a postback?

Tags: jqgrid

In some case, I'm okay with the groupingGroupBy making a postback to the server.

But in some cases, I need to do multilevel grouping without making a postback.  Can that be done?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupingGroupBy` method changes mostly `groupingView` option and reload the grid by triggering of `reloadGrid`. If need that the grid will be *locally* grouped then you can to use either `datatype: "local"` or `loadonce: true`. Only in the case the data returned from the server will be saved locally and it can be grouped locally by `groupingGroupBy` method.